# 404 on django pipeline staticfiles when using multiple deployments with different app versions

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

I have two different websites that run the same app but they may differ a bit in their versions.

The problem I am encountering is when I deploy one site, if the version hash changes, the other site breaks as well. It looks to me like the hashes are stored in an external resource.

How do I force each instance of the application to serve their own version of the staticfiles?

Here are my configs:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

When we deploy, we run `collectstatic`, put everything into a static contents directory, and serve that using nginx.

We also use a CDN as a reverse proxy to hit the static files, ie

`client => mysite.mycdn.com/mystaticfile => nginx`

I initially thought there was a CDN configuration issue so I cut out the CDN on one of the apps, but the issue persists.

Comment: As it may impact the answer, can you provide more information about how they are being hosted/served currently?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser updated